# Perl - Custom Error Output

Tags: perl, error-handling

I need to know how to customize my own errors in Perl.  For instance, here's some code:

```
my $filename = 'filaname1.exe';
print "Copying $filename";
copy("$dir_root\\$filename", "$spcl_dir\\$filename");
if ($? == "0") {
    print " - Success!\n";
}
else { print " - Failure!\n"; }
```

I tried to write this and "catch" the error and print "Failure" when I don't get an exit code of 0, and print "Success" when I do.  I need to know how I can customize this; I don't really want to use `die` or anything like that where it will give a somewhat cryptic error (to the end user).

Thanks!

Comment: Use /slashes/ not \\\\backslashes\\\\ in /path/names.

Comment: If `die` gives mysterious and unintelligible messages, on your head be it, since you’re who’s passing the cryptic argument to `die`.  You’ve no one else to blame.

Comment: Those are **terrible** error messages.  A good error message [1] goes to `STDERR` [2] includes `$0`, the name of the program that encountered the error as a minimum, and perhaps the function name; internal errors usually also give a stack trace [3] includes `$!`, the standard system error message wherever it’s appropriate, or perhaps `$?` or `$@` otherwise [4] states the name of the failed syscall [5] lists the arguments you gave that call. Your message neglects all, or nearly all, of those Five Rules for Good Error Messages.

Comment: One does not quote numeric literals in Perl. You’re just begging for trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to read the documentation on $? in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). This value is:

> The status returned by the last pipe
>   close, backtick ("``") command,
>   successful call to wait() or
>   waitpid(), or from the system()
>   operator.

Your call to copy (presumably from File::Copy) doesn't far into any of those categories, so $? isn't set.

However, if you read the documentation for [File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File%3a%3aCopy), you'll see that its function all "return 1 on success, 0 on failure". So you can simplify your code a lot.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

use File::Copy;

if (copy('notthere', 'somewhere else')) {
  warn "success\n";
} else {
  warn "failure: $!\n";
}
```

Note that I've used "warn" rather than "print" so that the errors go to STDERR. Note, also, the use of $! to display the operating system error. This can, of course, be omitted if it's not user-friendly enough.

Comment: Thanks - this worked great!  While djsadinoff's solution will also work, I liked the simplicity of the if statement embedded into the main command, something I'm very familiar with as I am mostly a PHP developer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using File::Copy?  You must be using something, because copy() isn't a perl keyword or built-in function.

The [documentation of File::Copy](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/perl-5.12.2/lib/File/Copy.pm) doesn't refer to $? at all, so that's probably your mistake.  You want to check the return value, and only if it's zero, refer to $!.

```
use strict;
use File::Copy qw(copy);
my ($from, $to) = @ARGV;
my $res = copy ($from, $to);
if( $res ){
  print "Okay\n";
}
else{
  print "Not Okay: $!\n";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm using `File::Copy`.  I might go with something else (using `system(@args)`, but for now `File::Copy` is working well.